# Android array list from database

Tags: android, arrays, cursor, spinner

I wanna create an array of cities that are stored in the database

Cities Table

```
CREATE TABLE cities (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);
```

Querying for City List

```
// City List
public Cursor cityList() throws SQLException {
    return db.query(TABLE_CITIES, new String[] {ID, KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Trying to Get the content into the Array

```
    Cursor cities = db.cityList();
    startManagingCursor(cities);

    String[] city_list = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME };
    Spinner cityList = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.citySpiner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, city_list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    cityList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Am not able to populate the Spinner.. with the database content.

Comment: hi harsha did you get any error while executing this... Also check whether the cities cursor has some content in it..

Comment: dinash.. no it doesnt have. it just had the column name :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SimpleCursorAdapter`

```
String[] from = new String[] {  DBAdapter.KEY_NAME  };
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item , cursor, from, to);
cityList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

**Edit:**

`from` means the column(s) from the `Cursor` which will be used to display as text array in `Spinner`.
`to` means the id(s) of the view which will hold the value of that column.
It is very interesting that the view at index **N** will hold the text from column at **N**.

Comment: can u explain to me what is String from and int[] to ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation buddy :) its a little confusing but got the idea :)