# Saving Listview(records) offline in database in Android...?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I am fetching records using API and showing it in a listview, but that only works when I am connected to internet. I want to save those records offline so that the user can see them offline too.

Please help me with it..
Please provide some code sample.
Thanks

Comment: The other part of the answer is answered in [this Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979103/problem-populate-database-into-listview-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME = "dictionary";
private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            KEY_WORD + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_DEFINITION + " TEXT);";

DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE);
}
}
```